# How to solve remoting error 409 xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, remoting

Setup: MacBook Pro with VMWare running Win8. Using Visual Studio 2012.

Coming back to iOS development, I tried to just get a basic template test app (click me app) running to make sure everything is working, but during the deployment process (either simulator or device), I receive the following error in the output window:

> Saying hello to the remote server at http ://172.16.58.1:50754/
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.MonoTouch.Common.targets(139,3):
>   **error : The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.**
>   [C:\Users\Ramsay\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\HelloWorld_App3\HelloWorld_App3\HelloWorld_App3.csproj]
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.MonoTouch.Common.targets(139,3):
>   **error : Failed to retrieve info from the build server**
>   [C:\Users\Ramsay\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\HelloWorld_App3\HelloWorld_App3\HelloWorld_App3.csproj]
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.MonoTouch.Common.targets(139,3):
>   error : [C:\Users\Ramsay\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\HelloWorld_App3\HelloWorld_App3\HelloWorld_App3.csproj]
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.MonoTouch.Common.targets(139,3):
>   **error : Remote build step failed.** [C:\Users\Ramsay\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2012\Projects\HelloWorld_App3\HelloWorld_App3\HelloWorld_App3.csproj]
>   Done Building Project "C:\Users\Ramsay\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\HelloWorld_App3\HelloWorld_App3\HelloWorld_App3.csproj"
>   (_RemoteBuild target(s)) -- **FAILED**.
>
> **Build FAILED.**

Could not find any more information about this problem. I would appreciate any assistance on this matter.

Comment: Could you take a look at the mac build host log at ~/Library/Logs/Xamarin/MonoTouchVS/mtbserver.log? is there any further info there?

Comment: The only warning in the log is about outdated API docs "Apple docs needs to be updated". A Visual Studio popup appears each time I open an iOS project asking me if I want to update the API Docs, which I select yes but then nothing happens in Windows or the Mac build host (which are on the same machine). I have returned to iOS development today hoping that the latest update fixed this weird bug but nothing appears to have changed.